# Book XML information for RDF trasformation

Tags: xml, bibliography

where I can find an xml file with the information about books ?

Let me better explain. 
If I want an XML file about music and artist I can found it on MusicMoz (http://musicmoz.org/xml/)
If I want an XML file about music style I can found it on MusicMoz always at the same site.

For my application I need to find information about books ( Book title, Author, Abstract, Genre of the book, and so on ) but i'm not be able to find it !
I searched DBpedia, Freebase, RDF Book Mashup, but I have not found what I was looking for !
Can you advice me ?

Once found the file, my application needs to trasform from XML to RDF and then load the RDF in the internal model of jena so I can merge this data source with other data source.
Tia 
Danilo

Comment: Not really a question about RDF or semantics then - you want to know where to get bibliographic information (as XML). Retagged.

Answer (score 0):

The richest XML data format for this is MODS, which you can get from the Library of Congress for many items: http://lccn.loc.gov/94042974/mods

To look an item up with the Library of Congress, though, you'll need its LCCN, which you can usually fetch, given the ISBN, from OCLC's xISBN service: http://www.worldcat.org/affiliate/webservices/xisbn/app.jsp

There are multiple conventions for converting to RDF from MODS; you may want to explore MADS/RDF, one of the more authoritative ones: www.loc.gov/standards/mads/rdf/

If MODS is more complex than you need, you can also retrieve similar data from Amazon's affiliate API, and even OCLC's xISBN, mentioned above, provides the essentials.

[Posted with broken links because I'm a new user here and am subject to a two-link cap. Sorry for the inconvenience!]